# Naturally sort by column value in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I am working on the SQL query in which I want to sort the string on the basis of numbers.

I have one column (**Column Name is Name**) table  in which there are multiple fields. On using ORDER BY NAME, it prints in the following way:

```
hello_world
hello_world10
hello_world11
hello_world12
hello_world13
hello_world14
hello_world15
hello_world4
hello_world5
```

For the above query, I have used **ORDER BY NAME;** but it doesn't seem to print on the basis of numbers.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what SQL query I need to write or what changes I need to make in my SQL query above so that it prints everything on the basis of numbers, the o/p should be this:

```
hello_world
hello_world4
hello_world5
hello_world10
hello_world11
hello_world12
hello_world13
hello_world14
hello_world15
```

Comment: The value always starts with `hello_world` and ends with a number or are there other patterns?

Comment: Yes the values always start with hello_world and ends with a number.

Comment: Is there any way, we can achieve that in sql ?

Comment: it's because it orders each character in turn, and the 1 (first character in the 10, for example) is considered less than 4 (a character in the same position in another string), so that comes first (because all the characters previous to that are equal in both strings). Of course since it's a varchar column, it doesn't see them directly as numbers, they're just individual characters within the string.

Comment: Depending on your situation you could either a) change the values so that you use leading zeros for the lower values - e.g. `helloworld04` instead of `helloworld4`. Then 0 will be less than 1 and it will sort as you might have intended. Or b), create a new "order" column (of `int` data type) in the database specifically to store the number representing the order of the rows, and use that in your Order By clause. Or c) you could try extracting the number values from the existing string, casting as a number and then ordering by that resulting value.But it might impact performance in large tables

Comment: `hello_world04` and `hello_world05` would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you want a numeric ordering, then you need to create a numeric value to order on.

currently you have strings.

if the pattern is true, then you can use a combination of string manipulation to trim off the first characters, which should leave only numbers, then use TO_NUMBER() to convert for the ordering

something like

```
select name 
from mytable
order by to_number( replace( name, 'hello_world','' ))
```

Comment: @Randy: you're faster than I am :-)

Comment: @Randy hello_world is just a general example. Let us suppose we have any another word apart from hello_world.

Comment: @john: try `REGEXP_INSTR(name, '[0-9]')` and use the result as the start index of `SUBSTR`- Watch out for names without any number.

Comment: @Randy Can you make a fiddle for it ? It will be easy to visualize a problem then.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution for this particular case (where all the values have the same prefix) is:

```
order by length(name), name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   name,
         CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(name, '[0-9]') = 0 THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(SUBSTR(name, REGEXP_INSTR(name, '[0-9]')) AS INT)
         END AS progressive
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY progressive;
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this ? I tried in my editor but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: I have created the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t9WE9DuAHKHEJn2Qgw5tqg/1) from your answer but it doesn't seem to work. Let me know what changes I need to make.

Comment: "your answer doesn't seem to work". Does it give you an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

we can order it using replace and cast methods.
I tried the following query

```
select Name, cast(REPLACE(Name, 'hello_world', '') as UNSIGNED ) as repl from Users order by repl;
```

To generage sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

insert into Users(Name) values
('hello_world'),
('hello_world4'),
('hello_world5'),
('hello_world10'),
('hello_world11'),
('hello_world12'),
('hello_world13'),
('hello_world14'),
('hello_world15')
;
```

**EDIT**
query without replaced column,

```
    select City from Persons order by cast(REPLACE(City, 'hello_world', '') as UNSIGNED );
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ? It will be easy to visualize a problem then.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Here is fiddle which I have created from your answer https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t9WE9DuAHKHEJn2Qgw5tqg/2  Its sorting on the basis of repl. In the real picture I don't want to display repl. Is there any way we can hide ?

Comment: Edited the post and fiddle also

Answer (score -1):

Though the question is about mysql.

I tried in **sql server**.

```
create table #t1 (id varchar(100));

insert into #t1 (id) values ('Pq1'),('pq3'),('pq2')

select * from #t 
order by 
CAST(SUBSTRING(id + '0', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', id + '0'), LEN(id + '0')) AS INT)
```

Comment: If you know the user is using MySQL, why would you provide an answer in SQL Server (especially using proprietary functions such as `PATINDEX`)?